# Call API on if and else condition

Tags: flutter, dart

**My API Call code:**

```
Future selectedAgentData() async {
        var userId = widget.uId;
    
        if (widget.month == null || widget.month == '') {
          url = 'http//example.com/getMonthDetails.php?uid=' + userId;
          print('if blk $url');
        } else {
          url = 'http//example.com/getAgentMonthFilterLead.php?uid=' +
              widget.uuid +
              '&month=' +
              widget.month;
          print('else blk $url');
        }
        var response = await http.get(url);
        return response.body;
      }
```

Here, we call the API when we open the screen. It displays the current month records (if block executed) and when I pass the month then display the selected month data (execute the else block).
I got the current month data (if block data) but not else block data.

Comment: You should be using `Uri` class. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html

Answer (score -1):

Just `print(widget.month);` before `if`, see what `widget.month` was.

Comment: I got the widget.month else block also and inside else I received url is like http://example.com/API/getMonthDetails.php?uid=38&month=June but not display the response

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil then the API is not returning any value may be because it's expecting some other values other than what you're passing.

Comment: @iwpz, please avoid adding comments as an answer !!!

Comment: @OMiShah Sorry, I don't know this rule, I wont.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil does the variable ``widget.uuid`` hold any value? try to print this var in the else block and check the console.

Comment: @OMiShah, the both block get the response but when the else block is executed then it gives the error **A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'**

Comment: You can print every step's value, or debug this function step by step. There must somewhere went wrong.